# Copying Sqlite database file content in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm working for an iOS app that was earlier developed using phone gap. It is having a sqlite database for storing data. But now while developing the same app in native, I'm using core data for storing the data.

Now when the new native app replaces the old phone gap app on user's device, I want to copy data from already existing sqlite file into core data.

So when I run the application on device with phone gap build pre installed my app(native) replaces the old build as I'm using same bundle ID but I'm not able to find out the path to that sqlite file. Does sqlite file still exists in documents directory?

Comment: That seems like a strange decision; you could have carried on using sqlite and not required any migration at all.  As it stands now, you have to build a sqlite interface in order to read the old data and use CoreData to insert it into the new database during migration (migration being fully supported by iOS apps).

Comment: @Droppy: But the thing is I'm not able to access the sqlite file at all. If i'll get the path than I'll do the migration. Even if i've used sqlite, the same issue would've occurred because I'm not able to get the path for the already created sqlite file.

Comment: If you don't know where phone gap has stored the file, it must be in the documents folder and you'll need to write some code to show all files in the document folder.  However you will need to find a way to *replay* the migration.  iOS won't delete document files during the migration, so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an example old database file still installed on one of your devices you could try downloading the App off the device using the `Device manager` in Xcode.

Then you open up the bundle and search for your file. Then if you know its location / name you can simply access it, read it using some SQLite library and load the data into your CoreData backing store. Keep in mind you either want to mark it in `NSUserDefaults` or delete the old DB all together so your app does not keep on migrating ( And then maybe accidentally deleting new data from a user. ) I would choose for keeping the old one around for at least a version or 2 so you can verify that your migration works without bugs / deleting user data in the process.

Tip: It is probably a good idea depending on how big your database is to show the user some kind of progress or "migrating / optimizing db" while you're doing this. So you don't end up with the user adding more data to the database before you're done migrating.

Comment: @Droppy Isn't the documents / cache directory all downloaded in that container? I don't have a device at hand to showcase this right now but pretty sure apps are kept in a container, I have specifically read a CoreData database using sqlite from the command line before.

Comment: You mention downloading the app and searching the bundle.  There might be a database in there, but it would only be a "seed" database which is copied into the documents folder on first use.  This is because you cannot write into the app bundle.  You could probably get the latest database via iTunes, if the app supports app sharing (or whatever it's called), which gets the files from the app's document folder.  This is the database you want.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cg67o3bk51j534/Screenshot%202016-03-17%2016.02.28.png?dl=0   https://www.dropbox.com/s/rof91p0kjveiz6p/Screenshot%202016-03-17%2016.01.43.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes; that's the *Documents* folder and nothing to do with the app bundle.